# Is way i can react to an asynchronous action in vuex in a vue template

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I want to display a loading effect in a vue template whilst an asynchronous action in vuex is still running. But the loading effect doesn't seem to work. How do I fix it?. Is there any better way I can achieve this?

This is how I defined the action:

```js
actions: {
  signIn({ state }, user) {
    auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(userInfo.email, userInfo.password)
      .then(result => {
        return result
      })
  },
},
```

This how defined the dispatch in vue template method:

```
let loader = this.$loader.show()
this.$store.dispatch('signIn', this.user).then(() => {
  loader.hide()
})
```

I expected the loader to start when the action begins and end when the action ends but it starts and ends almost instantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `return` statement, that returns a `Promise` so you can `then` it in your component.

```js
actions: {
  signIn({ state }, user) {
    return auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(userInfo.email, userInfo.password)
      .then(result => {
        return result
      })
  },
},
```